# Twitch API login with asyc and Vue

Tags: vue.js, twitch, nuxt.js

Hi so I'm using **Nuxt** to create an application with Twitch and I want users to be able to login with Twitch.

I have the application in Twitch setup and I have the keys, however, I'm not sure how to implement a button so once clicks it fires and therefore the user is able to sign in.

Here's what I have

```
<button class="twitch flex justify-center absolute pin-l items-center p-8 uppercase text-white font-semibold tracking-wide w-full" @submit.prevent="twitch">
  <i class="fab fa-twitch pr-2 text-xl"></i> Sign in with Twitch
</button>
```

and I have the method defined like so

```
  methods: {
    twitch () {
      async twitch () {
        let { data } = await axios.get(`https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<key>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&scope=chat_login`)
        this.twitch = data
      }
    }
  },
```

After the user signs in I want to have access to the API so I can build what I want to build for my application, so I want to pull in all the data that the API provides.

This might be completely wrong so any help in pushing me into the right direction would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@nuxtjs/auth](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module) module

Although it dont have twitch provider, it would be pretty easy to add, see for example [google provider](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/blob/dev/lib/providers/google.js)

Or at least you will get the idea. And read in how [oauth2 work](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/)

Comment: I already have firebase handling normal sign in / sign out, using Nuxt auth won't overwrite firebase, right?